# Kafka topic to websocket

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to implement a setup where I have multiple web browsers open a websocket connection to my akka-http server in order to read all messages posted to a kafka topic.

so the stream of messages should go this way

```
kafka topic -> akka-http -> websocket connection 1 
                         -> websocket connection 2
                         -> websocket connection 3
```

For now I have created a path for the websocket:

```
val route: Route = 
 path("ws") {
   handleWebSocketMessages(notificationWs)
 }
```

Then I have created a consumer for my kafka topic:

```
val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(system,
  new ByteArrayDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
    .withGroupId("group1")
    .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
val source = Consumer
  .plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("topic1"))
```

And then finally I want to connect this source to the websocket in handleWebSocketMessages

```
def handleWebSocketMessages: Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
  Flow[Message].mapConcat {
    case tm: TextMessage =>
      TextMessage(source)::Nil
    case bm: BinaryMessage =>
      // ignore binary messages but drain content to avoid the stream being clogged
      bm.dataStream.runWith(Sink.ignore)
      Nil
  }
```

Here is the error I get when I try to use `source` in the TextMessage:

> Error:(77, 9) overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
>     (textStream: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[String,Any])akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage 
>     (text: String)akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage.Strict
>    cannot be applied to (akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte],String],akka.kafka.scaladsl.Consumer.Control])
>           TextMessage(source)::Nil

I think I'm making numerous mistakes along the way but I would say that the most blocking part is the `handleWebSocketMessages`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing, is to understand that source is of type : `Source[ConsumerRecord[K, V], Control]`. 
So, it's not something that you could pass as an argument of a TextMessage.

Now, let's take the websocket's point of view:

- An outgoing message is built for each message in the Kafka source. The message will be a TextMessage from a String transformation of the Kafka message.
- For each incoming message, just println() it

So, the `Flow` can be seen as two components: the `Source` & the `Sink`.

```
val incomingMessages: Sink[Message, NotUsed] =
  Sink.foreach(println(_))

val outgoingMessages: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
  source
    .map { consumerRecord => TextMessage(consumerRecord.record.value) }

val handleWebSocketMessages: Flow[Message, Message, Any]  
  = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(incomingMessages, outgoingMessages)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer worked after I used `Consumer.committableSource` instead of `Consumer.plainSource`, and `consumerRecord.record.value()` instead of `consumerRecord.getkey.toString`.